# Extract complex URL from XML with JS or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I am extracting data from a database using an API; the API returns data into an XML file.

I am able to put the API return into an XML file on my server, using PHP (file_get_contents() and file_put_contents()). For almost all my fields, I am able to parse the XML file I created and manipulate it using either PHP or javascript (i.e., I've done both successfully).

One of the field values I need to call is a complex URL that automatically downloads an image file.  I am able to call the field with the API, and it goes into the XML file with the rest of the fields.

However, both the PHP parser ( simplexml_load_file() ) or the Javascript parser ( XMLHttpRequest() ) fail to read the XML file with the complex URL field.  I know I have the write code for parsing because like I said, I can successfully manipulate any other field with these parsers.

How can I get at this agencyPhoto field?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<results count="4">
        <row id="14" created="2013-04-07 21:43:59" updated="2013-05-05 19:12:21">
            <agencyPhoto>https://fw.civicore.com/vtmentoring/index.php?downloadFile=1&table=agencies&field=agencyPhoto&check=969ac322f0347d4358bd3a7852b7b282&key=14</agencyPhoto>
        </row>
</results>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XML doesn't look valid. The URL contains unescaped `&` characters that are illegal. They should be escaped to `&amp;` Or put into CDATA. First fix this before continuing.

So either

```
<agencyPhoto>https://fw.civicore.com/vtmentoring/index.php?downloadFile=1&amp;table=agencies&amp;field=agencyPhoto&amp;check=969ac322f0347d4358bd3a7852b7b282&amp;key=14</agencyPhoto>
```

or

```
<agencyPhoto><![CDATA[https://fw.civicore.com/vtmentoring/index.php?downloadFile=1&table=agencies&field=agencyPhoto&check=969ac322f0347d4358bd3a7852b7b282&key=14]]></agencyPhoto>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the ampersands (`&`). Try replacing them with `&amp;`
ie

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <results count="4">
    <row id="14" created="2013-04-07 21:43:59" updated="2013-05-05 19:12:21">
        <agencyPhoto>https://fw.civicore.com/vtmentoring/index.php?downloadFile=1&amp;table=agencies&amp;field=agencyPhoto&amp;check=969ac322f0347d4358bd3a7852b7b282&amp;key=14
</agencyPhoto>
    </row>
</results>
```